Tensorflow creating CNN for Matrix Completion PYTHON 3.9.19
I have an issue with building a modell to fit my problem. First ill explain what the objective is:

This is just an example of what it looks like, they are points in a picture, and due to distortion from the camera the bottom points are closer togehter.
I have successfully trained the 2 and 3 point version (Examples will follow), meaning I have an acceptable MSE.
The Matrix is generated by an algorithm and the input data is valid and good.
My issue is finding a general way to build the modell for this problem.
Because I couldnt find one for 2-12 Columns, I am seperating them into 2,3,4... different models and another Functional Model will Gate to the correct one.
My Problem lies with the 4 Column Matrix.
Examples of the Graph:

Next Example:

as you can see there are many factors:

Distortion on X and Y axis
Eucledian Distance changing
The Whole matrix being shifted a little

Why am I doing this?
I have a Modell getting a Matrix from a Picture, sometimes there are missing points, those need to be guessed so there can be a boolean saved to it, the Coordinates need to be close but definetly not perfect so I can map an X for the detected "Box" in the picture.
To get a picture in ur head, remove 1 of the points in the Matrix (Picture), that will be fed into the Model.
Sample In and Output with my 2Point modell:
   Original Input (with missing values): 
    [[ 2.47676975e+03  2.82050726e+03  3.17796255e+03  3.01837722e+03
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    2.65311183e+03  2.37574233e+03  3.11559301e+03  2.36508100e+03
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    2.55741407e+03  1.83704085e+03 -1.00000000e+00 -1.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]
    True Solution: 
    [[[2476.76974626 2820.50726156 3177.96254942 3018.37721602]
    [2653.11183202 2375.74233208 3115.5930063  2365.08100024]
    [2557.41406956 1837.04084636 3127.15366488 1935.48580718]]]

    Predicted Solution: 
    [[[2486.3933 2831.6006 3156.987  2966.4358]
    [2590.7405 2355.6292 3127.5642 2420.4702]
    [2579.9924 1842.941  2993.9897 1841.9865]]]

Zeros are padding and can be ignored, -1 marks a row with a missing value.
The slight shift in all the other points isnt that cruicial, since only the -1 Points will be needed and inserted to the Input Matrix.
-1 is just a placeholder appended to the end of the row if the row is shorter than another.
Its always XY XY Coordinates per row in this case
The Model gets padded to the Max of 12 Columns so the Gate Model can Handle the input.
The version with 12 Columns has no padding i.E.
Thank you for helping me:D
My first language is not english, if you have any questions or something is unclear please ask!
I have tested and tried a lot, Please dont hate this model, its just random Neurons and Layers at this point).
Does anyone have an idea for me how I should go about this?
I dont really care about performance (Batch and epochs can be anything if it works)
   current_column_testing=4
def create_model(max_columns):
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(72, input_dim=max_columns * 3 * 2, activation='relu'),  # Input shape
        # Dense(144, activation='gelu'),
        Dense(288, activation='gelu'),
        Dense(576, activation='linear'),
        #Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        Dense(current_column_testing*2*3, activation='relu'),
        Reshape((3, current_column_testing*2))  
    ])
    
    opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error')
    
    return model

model.train_on_batch(batch_input, batch_output)

train_with_new_task(epochs=5001, batch_size=16)

These are the code Snippets, if u need any more I can provide, I just dont want to spam unnec. inform.
The input and output Dimensions are correct and can be ignored.
"current_column_testing" describes the amount of columns that are currently in use
Activations are just random at this point, same as layers.
Problem is MSE just stays high or oscillates, learning rate doesnt seem to affect it really, whatevery I try
Does anyone know a smart way to include a Convul Layer? Before or after the Dense? What Sizes? And what could be the best combination of activation functions?
I have tried many different combos with different Neurons, Gelu und Linear combo have given me the best results.
